# Redirecting the YUI Compressor's verbose output to a file

Tags: command-prompt, yui-compressor

I am calling the YUI compressor in as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin>java -jar c:\min\yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar -v c:\min\file1.js -o c:\min\file1-min.js > c:\min\output.txt
```

Is there a way to get the verbose output piped to a file?

Ive tried the > c:\min\output.txt (as above) but it just creates empty files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answering old question because I ran into the same problem today.

Looks like the verbose output is directed to the standard error output so...
Replace "> c:\min\output.txt" with "2> c:\min\output.txt"